# Is there an annotation to generate a warning if a callback parameter is not used?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I see a lot of answers for the opposite of this, or how to suppress unused "something".

What I want is different:

I have a method that provides a value to callback and often find myself not using it when in this case I want to enforce (or at least warn) if the parameter is not used.

Since Kotlin allows you to reference these by `it`, it often goes unused and unnoticed since there isn't an explicit variable for lint to report as "unused".

I assumed this was possible because `Material`'s `Scaffold` for Jetpack Compose does this and I get a warning if I don't use the `PaddingValues` provided.
However, I looked at the source and couldn't find any annotation for this.

There must be one right?
I really doubt this would be something Android Studio/lint would do for one particular library…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin annotation for it, compose `Scaffold` is using [this lint rule](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/b4252665c1768293fab5e45a403a21d6e96ee997/compose/material/material-lint/src/main/java/androidx/compose/material/lint/ScaffoldPaddingDetector.kt)